# How to show/call different-different activities from status notification bar in android

Tags: android

I have an app which has 3 dashboard items as an activity. So whenever there is an notification in status bar and clicked it should call that respective activity.

I know how to create notifications but i am stuck for calling respective activities on notifications. Also is there a way to differentiate a notification based on activities..?

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, [packagename]);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

Comment: thanks for the help it works..but mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification); what is the significance of **HELLO_ID** or it can any constant number..?

Comment: yes, you can put there a constant number (maybe for each different notification) and will be able to read in the called activity which notification is the calling one